# Two-time correlation function from probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation, stationary-processes

Given a continuous stochastic process $x_t$ defined by the following Langevin equation

\begin{equation}
    d x_t = dB_t +F(x_t)dt
\end{equation}
where $dB_t$ is a Wiener increment and $F(x_t)$ is a general force such that $F(x_t)=-V'(x_t)/2$. It can be shown that this process, in the steady state, is sampled by the probability distribution

\begin{equation}
    P(x)=N e^{-V(x)}
\end{equation}
where $N$ is just a normalization. From this, all moments can be computed, i.e. $E[f(x)]=\int dx f(x) P(x)$.

I would like to compute now a two-time correlation function in the steady-state, i.e. $E[x(t) x(0)]$? Is it possible to do so from the probability function we found before? How should one proceed?